# What is a React component - Invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs

Consider the following:

```
function Welcome(props) {
  return <h1>Hello World</h1>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<Welcome />, document.getElementById('root'));
// React.createElement(Welcome, null)
```

The same can be accomplished with by invoking the function directly, instead of using JSX:

```
ReactDOM.render(Welcome(), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Now I'm not suggesting you *should* do this, but I've seen components invoked this way many times, i.e.

```
<div>
  {SomeComponentOrJSX()}
</div>
```

And it works.

However, it falls apart when you try and use hooks:

```
function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  return (
    <>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(x => x + 1)}>Increment</button>
    </>
  )
}
```

This will only work if you render it using `React.createElement(Counter, null)` or `<Counter />`

```
// Works
ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

It does not work if you invoke the function directly

```
// Does not work
ReactDOM.render(Counter(), document.getElementById('root'));
```

The error it provides is the infamous

```
  Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
```

Why is this?

The easy answer here is to not do that. Agreed. However, I want to dive deeper as to why this fails in this scenario.

I used to think that a React component was just the function definition but now I'm no so sure. According to this a React component to me is not only the definition alone but also the creation of the element using `React.createElement()`

Comment: What a component "is" is a great question. Highly suggested reading: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/react-components-elements-and-instances-90800811f8ca There are components, elements, and instances. A react component is a function or class which returns react elements. You can return jsx (elements) from functions but they won't be made into instances unless you plumb them through createElement

Comment: This looks like exactly what I'm looking for. I'll read and report back!

Comment: Digging into your last statement, even if I don't use JSX the example still fails -- which makes sense, I'm still just returning elements.

Are you saying that a component doesn't become an instance until it's passed to `React.createElement()`?

Comment: Hmm, I think I was incorrect saying that createElement makes it an instance. And from the article, functional components don't have instances. It seems like something about createElement in this case is telling hooks they're in the right context to be used. The source says it's because there's no "dispatcher" https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/ddd1faa1972b614dfbfae205f2aa4a6c0b39a759/packages/react/src/ReactHooks.js#L28-L29 but I don't know the "why" of createElement making hooks work

Answer (score 0):

As you might know, e.g. `<Hello />` translates to `React.createElement(Hello, null);`, and `React.createElement` in turn returns a magic object that React knows how to manage (and as such, any `React.createElement` call we can dub a "component boundary").

React keeps stringent track of component boundaries (and the Rules of Hooks only matter within component boundaries, mind). Hooks (like the lifecycle methods for class components!) are magic that occur during React's render phase; if you call `Hello()` directly, you're subverting the component lifecycle, and as such, the magic that hooks are is lost and things break. (For class components, you might do `(new ClassComponent(someProps)).render()` to do the same.)

Comment: What do you mean by component boundaries? Also your "magic" hand waving is not super helpful in helping me understand :/

Comment: Sorry! Edited the answer to try and explain component boundaries a little closer -- `<Foo><Bar /><Bar /></Foo>` has 3 components (one Foo, two Bars); `<Foo>{Bar()}{Bar()}</Foo>` has one component (Foo).

Comment: Do you have any resources on "component boundaries?" I've never heard that terminology before. I think I understand what you're saying, that because the function component wasn't passed to `React.createElement` a boundary wasn't created but where can I learn more about that instead of it just being magic?

Comment: I think I've borrowed the term "boundary" from React error boundaries (https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html), but I basically mean anything delimited (tree-wise) by a JSX tag.